# How to use tensorflow federated library in google colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am trying to use the tensorflow_federated library in google colab but cannot figure out how to do this. I have searched a lot on the internet for the same, but everywhere it's given, you don't need to install this library in google colab and you can use it directly, but I am not able to do so. Can anyone who has used this library in google colab tell me how to install/directly use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [TensorFlow Federated Tutorials Overview](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/tutorials_overview) there are links to 10+ colab notebooks. Navigating to any of them, and then clicking on *Run in Google Colab* should open the notebook in colab and demonstrates how to use.

Notably, TensorFlow Federated is *not* installed by default in Google Colab, rather all of the notebooks start with the following cell:

```py
!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated
!pip install --quiet --upgrade nest-asyncio

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

which installs TensorFlow Federated, as well as the `nest-asyncio` package which is needed for TensorFlow Federated's use of `asyncio` inside the event loop of colab itself.